# False Negative: Job Step History

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have written a query to use in a stored proc to obtain the Job Step history of individual steps within every Agent job that I have setup.   I thought I had the everything working fine until I noticed a flaw in my design.

I tried to use the 'job_outcome' column in msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps to determine if a job failed, succeeded, or was canceled until I noticed that some steps that never were executed were coming back as 'Failed.    I realize now that I have to look at the 'last_run_duration' column as well, but I am not sure how to re-work my query to include that.   Should I try a different approach or could someone suggest how I could rework the case statement in the following to resolve the issue?

```
    select  convert(varchar(75), j.name) as [JobName]
    , s.step_id
    , convert(varchar(75), s.step_name) as [StepName]
    , case s.last_run_outcome
        when 1 then 'Success'
        when 0 then 'Failed'
        when 3 then 'Cancelled' end as [StepStatus]
    , h.message
    , max(s.last_run_date) as last_run_date
    , max(s.last_run_time) as last_run_time
    , MAX(s.last_run_duration) as last_run_duration
    , max(ja.next_scheduled_run_date) as next_run   
    from msdb.dbo.sysjobs j 
inner join msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps s on j.job_id = s.job_id
left join msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory h on s.job_id = h.job_id
    and s.step_id = h.step_id
    and s.last_run_date = h.run_date
    and s.last_run_time = h.run_time 
left join msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity ja on s.job_id = ja.job_id
    where j.enabled = 1
    group by j.name, s.step_id, s.step_name, s.last_run_outcome, h.message
    order by j.name, s.step_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your `case` expression to be included in another `case` that first checks the `last_run_date`:

```
, case when MAX(s.last_run_date) > 0 then
      case s.last_run_outcome
          when 1 then 'Success'
          when 0 then 'Failed'
          when 3 then 'Cancelled' end
      else 'Never Ran' end as [StepStatus]
```

You suggested checking `last_run_duration`, but that can be zero if the job executed very quickly...

Comment: Thanks!  That seemed to solve the issue I was having.   I never thought to use 2 case statements for some reason.